# Angular2 Component's Context inside jQuery timpicker method

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

My use case :I am creating a time picker component for angular2.
 I need to pass Angular2 Components value to the jQuery timpicker, so i can set the values such as minTime, maxTime etc.

Here's the code

```
export class TimePicker{
   @Input() minTime : string;
   @Input() maxTime : string;
   @ViewChild('timePicker')    tmElement : ElementRef;

   ngAfterViewInit(){
     $(this.tmElement.nativeElement).timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
            minTime: '11',  --> Need this.minTime ?? 
            maxTime: '6:00pm',  --> Need this.maxTime ??
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true,
            change: (time)=> {
                this.changedTime(time);
            }
        });
       }


changedTime(time : Date){
  // This is called easily due to fat arrow
}
```

Ive tried using bind method but to no help. Since i look forward on using jQuery here and there this implementation would be helpful on the long way.
Thankyou :)

Comment: What is the problem? Is the `changedTime()` function not called at all? Is the timepicker not shown?

Comment: Also, it seems to work in this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/XHsn5kcWom9Istz8e8WV?p=preview

Comment: changedTime() is called, problem is setting the values such as minTime maxTime

Comment: @Robba can u add the minTime & maxTime values through the inputs like `<time-picker [minTime]='''6'" [maxTime]="'10:00'"></time-picker>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this.

declare var minTimeVal & maxTimeVal in method and use the same.

```
export class TimePicker{
   @Input() minTime : string;
   @Input() maxTime : string;
   @ViewChild('timePicker')    tmElement : ElementRef;

   ngAfterViewInit(){
     var minTimeVal = this.minTime;
     var maxTimeVal = this.maxTime;

     $(this.tmElement.nativeElement).timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
            minTime: minTimeVal, 
            maxTime: maxTimeVal,
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true,
            change: (time)=> {
                this.changedTime(time);
            }
        });
       }


changedTime(time : Date){
  // This is called easily due to fat arrow
}
```

Comment: ohh!! this was pretty straight!! thank @amol , one more thing suppose im using a config class where i put the minTime and maxTime inside it how would i then access it, ive used the plunker provided by   https://plnkr.co/edit/4wtqpLZUOLN92t4PkRhA?p=preview

Comment: @PratikKelwalkar you can import that same class in component using ("import { Config } from '../shared/index';") or constant variable in EnvConfig